# Azure Search > The data is temporarily unavailable on all of the fields of the resource

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I was working with an Azure Search Service, to be honest, quite confortably but suddently when I refreshed my portal, it showed that all of the fields of the resource are unavailable. Nevertheless, the app is still working. The issue is that my app is still in dev so I was intending to add several more indexes and indexers but I can not manage them anymore.

Hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the Azure Cognitive Search controllers. We are currently rolling them back, and hope to have things back to normal in the next hour or so.